# how to upload a file in to asset folder in silverstripe framework

Tags: javascript, php, html, silverstripe

i am getting a file from a input field in html page.then sending it to the php through anjular js. I need to upload this file to the asset folder in silverstripe framework. I searched lot but i only found that uploading from cms. But my file is not coming from the cms. Plz help me i am new to the field

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? We can't be much help without a reproducible example.

Comment: for the time being i cantshare the code.i am try to input a image from my computer and i get input data to anjular js scope object.then pass to the php. in php code i nedd to upload the image file in to asset folder. in php code i have this code.    $postData=file_get_contents("php://input");   i am getting all the attributes to the variable $postdata.now i need to upload this to asset folder.how can i do this?plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because not enough rep but if you're getting images from outside SilverStripe you can save files directly into the assets folder and they'll appear in the CMS. Note that you may need to run `http://yoursite.com/dev/tasks/FilesystemSyncTask` for them to appear.

*The Files & Images system in SilverStripe maintains its own database of the contents of the assets/ folder. This action will update that database, and should be called whenever files are added to the assets/ folder from outside SilverStripe, for example, if an author uploads files via FTP.*

Comment: i am try to input a image from my computer and i get input data to anjular js scope object.then pass to the php. in php code i nedd to upload the image file in to asset folder.can i do it using your method?for the time being i cant include my rep.sorry for that.

Comment: i am using a web site for clients. when they insert an image, they dont know to run the url that you have provided i guess.is there any way to do this?

Comment: It is possible to have user uploaded content work well without having to run that link but you would need to create a separate DataObject / Controller to handle the incoming file. You would need to save it using SilverStripes functionality rather than PHP so it correctly works with the CMS. Try [reading this](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/form-questions/show/22062), it's a solution to a similar problem you're having

Comment: I advise against using Sync Files in v3.4.0. I have run it two days ago directly from the CMS while in a subfolder of assets and that operation caused the loss of ALL files, not just those in the folder. The physical files remained on the filesystem, but database entries of files I had ever uploaded and that were still on the filesystem were gone. DB records of files that no longer were on the filesystem remained :-) Fortunately, this was a development instance so I just imported the DB.